# Z value bigger than 1 after w division

Tags: opengl, perspectivecamera

What I am doing in vertex shader is:

```cpp
shadowCoord = shadowVP * mMatrix *  vec4(vertex_position,1.0);
```

Now to get it back in the range [**-1**, **1**] I did this in the fragment shader:

```cpp
vec3 proj = shadowCoord.xyz / shadowCoord.w;
```

But if I test the z value of such point I get a value bigger than **1**.

The perspective matrix I use is obtained via:

```cpp
glm::perspective(FOV, aspectRatio, near, far);
```

And it results in:

```cpp
[2.4142  0      0      0 
 0     2.4142   0      0
 0       0    -1.02   -1
 0       0    -0.202   0]
```

and the shadowVP is:

```cpp
shadow_Perp * shadow_View
```

Shouldn't `proj.z` be in the range [**-1**,**1**]?

Comment: No, that would require clamping. This will still produce results outside that range, you either need to decide to clamp them (as might be done with texture coordinates) or clip them (as might be done with vertices).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I've understood. Provided that I totally understood the issue pointed out by derhass , in a case where the point lies in the frustum, didn't the perspective multiplication + division by w automatically make every value between in [-1; 1]? Or are you saying that if I should do clip  /clamp to consider the out of frustum case?

Comment: No, if you do not understand this then you actually do not understand the point derhass was making either. Division by `w` can still produce values outside of the range [**-1**, **1**], those points are outside of your viewing volume. When this division is done by the actual graphics hardware prior to transformation into NDC space, points with coordinates > w or < -w are clipped. This is not something that happens automatically, and when you do the division yourself it ignores this fact, thus you can still have points outside that range after division.

Comment: In the case of projective texture coordinates, which is what you are actually using here, GL actually takes care of coordinates out of the range [**0.0**,**1.0**] for you using its texture wrap state. The default is `GL_REPEAT`, which means that **-1** becomes **0** and **-0.1** becomes **0.9**. Even if you go way outside of that range, it works the same - **-33.0** becomes **0.0** and **-33.1** becomes **0.9**. The input coordinates do not need to be in a particular range, texture sampling will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't `proj.z` be in the range [-1,1]?

No. It is in the range [-1,1] if the point lies inside the frustum. And the frustum is defined as `-w <= x,y,z <= w` for any vetrex in clip space (and that `w` varies per vertex). But you don't do any clipping, so any value can result here. Note two things:

1. While I said the implication "`v` inside the frustum" => "NDC coords in [-1,1]" holds true, the opposite does not. That means you can get the NDC coords inside [-1,1] for points which lie outside of the frusutm (that might even lie behind the "viewing position").
2. You might also get the division by 0 here.